# How can I get the whole text content from a Paragraph(System.Windows.Documents)?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, paragraph, inlines

I think the question title is self explaining enough.
I've added some strings via `ParagraphControl.Inlines.Add(SomeStringValue)` and I'm getting some troubles retrieving the text content. Any tip?

I've tried to get the text from the `Inline` itself and then flatten the string collection via `String.Join()`

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to achieve it.

```
Text = String.Join(String.Empty, ParagraphControl.Inlines.Select(line => line.ContentStart.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method I use.  A `Paragraph` is a `TextElement`, as are some other things in System.Windows.Document.

```
public static string GetText(this TextElement textElement)
{
    return new TextRange(textElement.ContentStart, textElement.ContentEnd).Text;
}
```

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-extract-the-text-content-from-a-richtextbox